# Delta Lake error SparkFileNotFoundException when looking for _delta_logs in local docker container

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, docker-compose, delta-lake

I'm running delta lake on my local host. I setup a **spark-master**, 2 **spark-workers**, and one **spark-driver** docker container. Inside the **spark-driver** container is where I run `spark-submit` that points to `spark://spark-master:7077` . The spark-driver connects to spark-master, however it can not find _delta_log files. I receive the following error even though the file exists.

> org.apache.spark.SparkFileNotFoundException: File
> file:/opt/ufo-lakehouse/lakehouse/ufo/bronze/_delta_log/00000000000000000000.json
> does not exist

Here is a snippet of my **docker-compose.yaml** . As you can see I have the volumes mapped correctly.

```
version: '3.8'

networks:
  spark-network:

x-defaults:
  &spark-common
  image: bitnami/spark:3.4.0
  user: root
  networks:
    - spark-network
  volumes:
    - ./lakehouse:/opt/bitnami/spark/lakehouse
    - ./logs/spark:/opt/bitnami/spark/logs
    - ./src/spark/spark-defaults.conf:/opt/bitnami/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf

services:
  spark-master:
    <<: *spark-common
    container_name: spark-master
    hostname: spark-master
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
      - SPARK_MASTER_HOST=spark-master
      - SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077
      - SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=8080
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 7077:7077
```

I tried everything I could with permission and nothing seems to work. I also set `spark.hadoop.fs.permissions.umask-mode` to `000` thinking spark was writing files with the wrong permissions but this didn't help either. Are there any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Logs suggest it's looking for the file in `/opt/ufo-lakehouse/lakehouse/ufo/bronze/_delta_log/00000000000000000000.json`, but your volume is mounted at `/opt/bitnami/spark/lakehouse`
Can you confirm exactly where the _delta_log folder exists inside the container?

Comment: I can confirm in my 'spark-driver' container (not shown in the above docker-compose file), that the delta lake program created bronze, silver, and gold directories with _delta_log folder and the .json file that it says its missing. I can also see the folders on my local host are created (outside of the docker container). However, even though the .lakehouse directory is mapped to spark-master and spark-worker, the lakehouse directory is empty in those containers. Do I also need to map each sub directory?